# Android: How to calculate speed of the mobile internet(Upload speed) using signal strength by programatically

Tags: android, telephonymanager, connectivity, signal-strength

In Android, I was able to find strength of signal using below code,

```
   protected int getSignalStrength(SignalStrength signal) {
            String ssignal = signal.toString();
            String[] parts = ssignal.split(" ");

            int dB = -120; // No Signal Measured when returning -120 dB

            // If LTE 
            if (telephonyManager.getNetworkType() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE){

                int ltesignal = Integer.parseInt(parts[9]);

                // check to see if it get's the right signal in dB, a signal below -2
                if(ltesignal < -2) {
                    dB = ltesignal;
                }
            }
            // Else 3G
            else {

                if (signal.getGsmSignalStrength() != 99) {

                    int strengthInteger = -113 + 2 * signal.getGsmSignalStrength();
                    dB = strengthInteger;   
                }
            }

            return dB;
        }
```

How to calculate speed of the mobile internet(Upload speed / download speed) using signal strength by programatically?? this is my quesion?

Comment: signal strength doesn't correspond to download/upload speeds

Comment: how can find speed of data upload n download...can yo tell me pls

Comment: Source code for speedtest.net, this might help you :http://www.gregbugaj.com/?attachment_id=70

Comment: Is there any diffrence for upload speed and download speed because above ur link say download speed. so can you tel me properly.. Thanku for suggestions

Comment: You can't calculate the speed, you have to measure it. And how can you measure upload speed? By uploading something somewhere and measuring how long it takes.

Comment: And wherever you upload that file has to have enough bandwidth to not become the bottleneck, so you need a powerful server with insane bandwidth even if you want to just support a few concurrent users. More than that you probably need servers all over the world so latency doesn't become an issue. So all in all: it's really really difficult to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook released a library for this:

https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class

Library Description:

Listen to current network traffic in the app and categorize the quality of the network.

Comment: i imported project in android studio, getting ** import javax.annotation.Nonnull; ** error...can you tell me the dependency i need to add, i tried with  compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations:7.0.2' but not solved

Comment: You can add library with gradle just add `compile 'com.facebook.network.connectionclass:connectionclass:1.0.1'` to your app gradle dependencies.